# Including images in GeoJSON

Tags: geojson

Is there a correct way of including links to images within geoJSON?

This is the FeatureCollection I have for [an object on my site](https://openbenches.org/bench/1234):

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "id": 1234,
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -0.322825,
          51.065361
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "popupContent": "In loving memory of\r\nGordon Wiseman\r\n15.4.30 ~ 11.8.06\r\nWho spent many happy hours\r\nin this park"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I also want to include the links to multiple images.  Is it OK to add another property? For example:

```
"properties": {
    "popupContent": "In loving memory of\r\nGordon Wiseman\r\n15.4.30 ~ 11.8.06\r\nWho spent many happy hours\r\nin this park",
    "media": [
        "https://example.com/image1.jpg",
        "https://example.com/image2.jpg"
    ]
}
```

Or is there a better / more standard way of doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK GeoJSON is [standardized](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946) by the *Internet Engineering Task Force* (IETF), and the standard mainly defines the implementation of geographic objects.

The properties are based on and extended from the `{key: value}` structure of JSON itself; you can populate it with anything that fits this concept.

The exact contents should be tailored to the parsing capabilities of your target software; it's likely some frameworks/systems can automatically parse image URLs from a dedicated property.

For interchangeability, I would probably stick to the standard `properties: {key: value}`, just like you did.

In many applications, properties are treated as attributes/field/columns...you can add as many as the target system allows. However, I would avoid furrther nesting of property objects.